# Firebase limit upload retry

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to limit the upload retrial time in firebase storage on iOS to be able to give feedback to my user in a reasonable time. I know that I am supposed to change `Storage.storage().maxUploadRetryTime` however, when I am editing this variable nothing is changing!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can make these changes only in your storage rules. Do you know the basics of node.js?

Comment: where exactly? on the firebase console?

Comment: Yes mate, your fire base storage and the rules section

Comment: could you give me the required syntax?

Comment: It's based on your database structure mate, unfortunately I can't

Comment: am afraid we're talking about different things since the android guy did it locally! Thanks for the help